# how to generate IMIE from device id

Tags: java, android, imei

Some android devices don't have an IMEI, but my app usses it for registration on a website. All devices have unique device ID though. It looks like this - "00000000-54b3-e7c7-0000-000046bffd97".

How can I generate 15 integers from this ID and be pretty sure that other device won't generate same number?

Comment: use android deviceId for it

Comment: do you want to generate unic id?

Comment: I want to generate unique 15 digit number on device. Preferably from device id, preferably to be 100% sure  the same 15 digits can't be generated on any other device.

Comment: IMEIs are not guaranteed to be unique - they should be unique however in reality duplicate IMEIs (error, manipulation, ...) are possible.